# If I import my ME3 Shepard into a new game, will the old save still be there?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I have finished the game in ME3 and want to import this Shepard into a new game, will I still have the original finished ME3 save there to go back to?

I have finished the game on insanity but forgot to save Jack so need to go back and do that, but don't want to to the whole game again, I just want to get the achievement. 
However, when the new DLC comes out with the extra bits on the end, I also don't want to have to redo the whole game just to see the extra ending.

Too scared to try it in case I stuff everything up

UPDATE: so I bit the bullet and started a new game with my original shep and all is fine. Still have the original, unchanged. I just now have 2 saves with the same name, but the date is different so that's how I can tell them apart. 
You can also change your appearance if you want, I just altered the hair colour slightly just so I can have a little difference. Will also use different gear. You start with all your stuff and points and can really kick donkeys. Insanity is a breeze now. Thanks for the answers folks.

Comment: not a bad question, been curious myself how starting a new game would work specifically with war readiness and war assests earned in multiplayer.

Comment: @Paralytic war assets from ME3 are not imported, war assets from previous games are imported the same as when you first imported the ME2 save. War readiness is global for all your characters and does not need to be imported.

Answer (score 3):

A Mass Effect 3 save will remain intact no matter how many times you import it. The original file will not be changed in any way.

Comment: Thanks, so I guess I will have saves/ gmes with the same name? Multiple games, same name?

Comment: At least on the Xbox 360, each time you create a new game (whether the save is imported or not) a new career is started. On the load game screen there is an option to switch careers, so you would use that to go back to your original game.